# Jump from textBox.Text to another textBox.Text

Tags: c#

I'm new by C# and I'm trying to write a program which adds by each click on a button the same number in textBoxes.

```
if (textBox1.Text == "1")
{
textBox2.Text.AppendText(textBox1);
}
```

When I click on the button, the number "1" will be at the same time added in both boxes. What should I do to add the number first in the first box and by the next click in the second box?

I will be so thankful for you help.

Comment: you missed to put `Text` property , do :`textBox2.Text.AppendText(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: `textBox2.Text += textBox1.Text;`

Comment: @ Ehsan Sajjad,
hello, it doesnt work with Text property by me. Please look at the pic below: enter image description here
@Dmitry Bychenko ,
i dont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use a Class scoped variable to count the number of times the button has been clicked, eg. `clickCount`, and then use that value to determine which textbox to update. For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int clickCount;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clickCount = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clickCount++;  // increment clickCount each time the button is clicked

        switch (clickCount)
        {
            case 1:
                textBox1.Text = "1";
                break;
            case 2:
                textBox2.Text = "1";
                break;
            case 3:
                textBox3.Text = "1";
                break;
            case 4:
                textBox4.Text = "1";
                break;
            case 5:
                textBox5.Text = "1";
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("clickCount outside of range (5)");
                break;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Excatly that i meant with Switch Case. Thank you so much, ^^

Answer (score -1):

After your comments I now understand what you are trying to do. There is a 'Tag' in the properties menu of the items, underneath the 'Data' column. What I would recommend doing is by default set the name of the first textbox inside of the data column. For instance if you have 5 textboxes named:
text1, text2, text3, text4, text5

Go into the design and set the 'Tag' to "text1"

Then your code should look like this:

```
switch(btnMyButton.Tag.ToString()){
   case "text1":
     text1.Text = (int.Parse(text1.Text) + 1).ToString();
     btnMyButton.Tag = "text2";
   break;
   case "text2":
     text2.Text = (int.Parse(text2.Text) + 1).ToString();
     btnMyButton.Tag = "text3";
   break;
   case "text3":
     text3.Text = (int.Parse(text3.Text) + 1).ToString();
     btnMyButton.Tag = "text4";
   break;
   case "text4":
     text4.Text = (int.Parse(text4.Text) + 1).ToString();
     btnMyButton.Tag = "text5";
   break;
   case "text5":
     text5.Text = (int.Parse(text5.Text) + 1).ToString();
     btnMyButton.Tag = "text1";
   break;
}
```

Comment: @ Jay Mason ; i have tried it with equal, but it does not work unfortenetely. When i click on the button the number will be add at the same time in both Boxes
Any solution please?

Comment: You put this check before you add 1 to textBox1. Add an IF-ELSE statement if you want to add one back and forth.

Comment: This isn't Java.  The `==` checks whether the contents of the strings are equal, not the references.  If you find a type where the `Equals` method and `==` operator for that type are different, then that's a bug in that type's definition, you should fix it if its your code, or tell the author to fix it if it isn't.

Comment: exactly, but i have 5 Boxs, where by every click should be ein "1" in every Box shown. Do i have to learn how to use break and case to solve the Problem?

Comment: While that is true that == and .equals for strings will work in C#, its still a reference type and you should be in consistent. Any other reference type will not return the same thing in C# - the only special case is strings.

Comment: @Reda You need to explain this better because it went from 2 text boxes, to 5. You have 1 button being pressed, and when it gets pressed you are doing what with the text boxes? Are you adding 1 to the value, or are you adding 1 to the string?

Adding to the value would mean that when you click the button, if the value was 1 you now get the value of 2. Doing what you have in your post of appendtext would mean your value is now 11

Comment: When i click on a Button 5 times, will be add in each Box the number "1"

Comment: Okay, so when you click on the button 4 times, what happens?

Comment: @JayMason String is not some special case.  Every type that overrides the `Equals` method is expected to override the `==` operator such that the two behave consistently.  You should always do so in all of your types, and you can expect all of the .NET types to do the same.  Again, *you should treat it as a bug if some type behaves differently* between the two operations, and you shouldn't expect to see such bugs in any .NET types.

Comment: @Servy He doesn't really care about the equals function or the ==, it doesn't matter. They are not the same thing when comparing reference types unless you override them. Move on

Comment: @Reda Please see the edit, this will do exactly what you want. Goodluck.

Comment: @JayMason But they *are* the same thing, even when comparing reference types, unless that reference type overrode the two in a way that results in them behaving differently, which they shouldn't, and *is a bug*.  If you don't override either then they will behave the same.

Comment: how can i call some values from the same TextBox. Example: Button_Click1: textBox1.Text="1"; int a=int.Parse(textBox1.Text); Button_Click2: textBox1.Text="+"; char b= char.Parse(textBox1.Text); Button_Click3: textBox1.Text="2"; int c=int.Parse(textBox1.Text); Button_Click4: int f = (a + '+' + b); textBox1.Text= (a + '+' + b) + "=" f; Output: 1 + 2 = 3